# regexec causing malloc error corrupted size vs. prev_size

Tags: regex, gcc, malloc

After several iterations of evoking regexec I'm getting a malloc error internal to regexec.

There is usually only one tag (reg exp) in the tag array so in the following code the value of tagidx in the loop is zero.  Stepping through the code shows a valid regular expression

```
^\"(.+)\",\"(.+)\"$
```

And the buffer contains a 0 terminated char* (string)

```
0x555555756160 <buffer> "\"PrimaryKey\",\"https://example.com/news/story/samplepage\""
```

So this function works several times before eventually failing with:

corrupted size vs. prev_size

Stack trace shows error from within malloc called from regexec.

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04, gcc 7.4.4.

```
void ProcessTags(FILE *infile, char *buffer, tag *tags)
{
  int tagcnt = sizeof(*tags)/sizeof(tag);
  int tagidx, errno;
  regex_t tagreg;
  regmatch_t matches[MAXMATCHES];

  for (tagidx = 0 ; tagidx < tagcnt ; tagidx++)
  {
    if((errno = regcomp(&tagreg, tags[tagidx].regexp, REG_EXTENDED)))
    {
      regerror(errno, &tagreg, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
      fprintf(stderr, "Regular expression problem with tag %s - %s : %s\n", tags[tagidx].tagname, tags[tagidx].regexp, errbuf);
    }

    if (regexec(&tagreg, buffer, MAXMATCHES, matches, 0) == 0) // SIGINT here!!!
    {
      switch (tags[tagidx].action)
      {
...
      }
    }

    regfree(&tagreg);
  }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(*tags)/sizeof(tag)` is always `1`. Is that intended?

Comment: `sizeof(*tags)/sizeof(tag)` won't give you the count. Consider passing that value as argument instead.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but fortunately for me it should always be 1!

Comment: Did you find a way to overcome this ?

Comment: No never.  Are you experiencing something similar?